# Create new variable as the FIRST value of another variable, sorted by a third variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a database like the following:

```
score_df <- tibble(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "Mex", "Mex"),
               year = c(2001, 2000, 1997, 2003, 1998, 2006),
               perc = c(5, 6,8, 8, NA, 10),
               score = c(NA, 400, NA, 423, 12, 18))
```

I want to create a new variable, `year_1_score`, that represents the FIRST (non-NA) year's score. In other words, `year_1_score` should be filled in for every row & meets the following criteria:
-Groups by country
-Arranges by year
-For each country, gest the first `score` that isn't NA
-Inserts this value for all cells for that country

I'd like the final df to look like this:

```
score_df <- tibble(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "Mex", "Mex"),
               year = c(2001, 2000, 1997, 2003, 1998, 2006),
               perc = c(5, 6,8, 8, NA, 10),
               score = c(NA, 400, NA, 423, 12, 18),
               year_1_score = c(400, 400, 400, 400, 12, 12))
```

I tried the following two attempts, but to no avail.

Attempt #1:

```
score_df <- score_df %>% 
group_by(country) %>% 
arrange(year) %>% 
mutate(yr_1_score = ifelse(year==min(year) & !is.na(score), score, NA)) %>% 
ungroup()
```

Attempt #2:

```
score_df <- score_df %>% 
group_by(country) %>% 
arrange(year) %>% 
filter(!is.na(score)) %>% 
slice(1) %>% 
mutate(yr_1_score = score) %>% 
ungroup()
```

Anyone able to crack problem? Solutions using dplyr are strongly preferred but any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first `arrange` the dataframe by `year`, then `group_by` `country` and select the first non-NA value for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

score_df %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(year_1_score = score[which.max(!is.na(score))]) %>%
  arrange(country)


#  country  year  perc score year_1_score
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 Mex      1998    NA    12           12
#2 Mex      2006    10    18           12
#3 US       1997     8    NA          400
#4 US       2000     6   400          400
#5 US       2001     5    NA          400
#6 US       2003     8   423          400
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thanks so, SO much, Ronak!

Do you mind explaining why the `score[which.max()]...` argument grabs the `score` from the first `year` rather than the LARGEST score for that country?

SO grateful for your super fast, super helpful response.

Comment: @wscampbell using `!is.na(score)` we get `TRUE/FALSE` values where `TRUE` means the value is not `NA`. `which.max` finds the first maximum value in that vector of `TRUE/FALSE` values where `TRUE` is considered as 1 and `FALSE` as 0 so `which.max` gets the index of first `TRUE` value in the vector and then we get the corresponding `score` using that index.